# Approach to instrument what code developers write vs what is brought in via modules (3rd party) in python

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, lines-of-code

I've been tasked with an interesting, but challenging problem. I'm trying to provide some semblance of a metric of how much code our in our 3400 odd repositories is authored by our developers, vs what is brought in via modules (both internal eg. os, system and external , eg requests, numpy). I'm concentrating on Python for now, as we have pretty good instrumentation via webpack within the Javascript space. I recognize this is a difficult question to see the value in and there's a ton of caveats in place, but I'm still wanting to pursue this answer. I've looked at the AST module, but can't identify an easy way to identify if code execution has jumped into a module that is 3rd party. Can anyone suggest a way of going about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess you'll want to start with something like this:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/modulefinder.html

After which, your probably going to need to check against a controlled list of in-house modules.

Of course, the above would only raise one instance regardless of how many times said module was used, so not sure is that really reflecting how much your in-house developers contribute.